# Projections on Nested Documents with Spring's MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I would like to perform a projection on a MongoDB document, which has a nested document. For example, say I have the following document:

```
Foo : {
      fooField1 : 1,
      fooField : 2,
      Bar : {
            barField : 1,
            barField : 2
      }
}
```

I would like to get the following back from my `mongoTemplate.aggregate(..)` call:

```
Foo : {
    fooField1 : 1,
    Bar : {
        barField1 : 1
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out a how to do this with the `MongoTemplate`. I have tried many different combinations, including:

```
Aggregation.project(Fields.field("fooField1").and("Bar").project(Fields.field("barField1"))
```

I haven't had any luck so far. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically need to `$unwind` nested data in the aggregation framework

After you unwind Bar, match it to FooField

Comment: I wish this answer were more detailed.